# Changing an image file type dynamically

Tags: html, facebook, image, file, facebook-opengraph

I have a bunch of images stored on the server but their names do not have their file types set. In other words, on the server I have a file `img/picture` instead of `img/picture.jpg`.

If I display this as source in an HTML `<img>` tag, the image is properly displayed in the web page:

```
<img src='img/picture' />
```

However, this causes other problems. For example, if I pass this link to the Facebook Open Graph, it does not consider it to be containing image. It requires something like `img/picture.jpg` but that is invalid file on the server since it doesn't exist there. I do not want to copy every image in the folder so that it ends with `.jpg` so I'm thinking if there's a way dynamically to create new image that's called `picture.jpg` and send that link to Facebook without saving it to my own server?

Comment: I doubt that Facebook demands any specific “ending” of image URLs; it might rather expect the correct MIME Type to be specified via the Content-Type header – and likely your server is not doing that (because the file is saved without a `.jpg` suffix, it is not able to determine the type automatically.) You could try setting the Content-Type via the [`ForceType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#forcetype) directive (assuming your using Apache).

Comment: I did set the og property for type, however, without success:
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">

If I send url as img/picture Facebook sees it as image but when shared it displays nothing. If I have img/picture.jpg though it works.